# Reasons for the slowness of a request on sql server

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.number AS Number, a.code AS Code, a.name AS Name, a.disabled AS Status, 
MAX(b.endDate) AS LastDate 
FROM [DATAB].[dbo].[TableA] AS a  with (NOLOCK), [DATAB].[dbo].[TableB] AS b with (NOLOCK) 
WHERE b.number = a.number AND b.accountNum = 'XXXXXXX' 
GROUP BY a.code, b.number, a.disabled, a.name, a.number
ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

This query returns 1400 rows.

On my local Machine(Windows 7, with 16GB ), the database is stored on SQL Server v11.00 SP2.
When I execute this query, I get the result list in 4s.

On a Windows VM, with 8 GB, the same database is stored on SQL Server 10.50 SP3.
When I execute this query, I get the result list in 2 mins...

It shouldn't take so long, I don't think the problem come from the VM configuration, but I'd like to know what could cause this slowness, any idea?

Comment: Impossible to answer. Try running this query and displaying estimated execution plan and see if ssms suggest you any index..

Comment: In addition: Installing MS SQL on a VM takes some performance - recently we've un-virtualized a SQL server due to a lack of performance after we found information about this possible reason somewhere in the MSDN.

Comment: post both of the execution plans

Comment: Well your slow machine has half as much memory. And being a VM it might not even have 8G allocated to it (it might be 'over provisioned'). Can you match the memory and re test? That's not the only thing that might be the problem but it's the only thing that can be gleaned from your question.